# How can I add a full background to an A4-sized Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, images, documents

I'm trying to add a background to an A4-sized Word document.

What is the correct background image size (in terms of resolution) to put into an A4 document?   I tried Watermark, Fill effects, and tried to put the image into the header as well.

The image doesn't fit correctly – it will be centered and I need to scale it without causing a quality drop.

Answer (score 4):

I have had to this a couple of times for a background you don't want noobs messing with.

795 x 1123 jpg worked for me on A4 in word. When using Fill ->picture function.

Answer (score 2):

Page Layout > Page Color > Fill Effects > Picture > Select Picture.

Use Paint.NET, create image of 210x297mm with 200+dpi resolution and use this image as background. This should work.

Tested with Word 2007.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple! Create a4 background image. Open word doc. Go in page setup and set footer, header  and all margins values as 0 (zero). Than follow the procedure for insert background image, and image will be calibrated

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the picture in "21 : 29.7" ratio by either corping or changing the aspect.
Then just insert the picture in the document and selecting "Behind the text" option from "Wrap Text" drop down menu. Lastly, adjust the position and size of that picture...

Answer (score 0):

i think the resolution must be `2480 * 3508`
when you make a new image as size `A4` in photoshop this is the resolution for it

Comment: Thanks for the reply.:). Yeah I tried this one and the same with resolution 100 as well. But the problem is when I insert the pic in word, it comes in center, not stretched.For this any solution?

Comment: @Midhun You never said anything about Word. I edited your question, please check if that's the real problem you have.

Comment: How does that link have anything to do with inserting a background into Word? And why would you need CorelDraw?

Comment: @ slhck. thanks..:) Yeah that is the prob I am facing. I think I have mentioned about word. I don't need Coreldraw, dint mention anything about it anywhere. I just want to know what would be the perfect size and perfect way to fit a bg image in word 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Save the image you wish to use as A4 size 210 x 297mm at 72DPI (very important) and this will fit perfectly using the Page Background > Colour > Fill Effects method.

Comment: Apple uses a default monitor pixel density assumption of 72 DPI.  Windows uses 96 DPI ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch#Computer_monitor_DPI_standards)).  This probably won't make a difference for a solid color fill, but might affect sharpness for a background photo.

Answer (score 0):

**Word page size A5 Format** 
Fist of all resize your image in width:768px Height:959px resolution 80(dpi)
Then Go to Insert tab> click picture > select your resize image > Go to position > click more layout option > select square then select wrapp text left only and click Ok. Go to format tab > Resize your width and height as per your need

Comment: What does A5 have to do with the question (which is about A4)?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the above and none worked out. I start doing my own trials and I nailed it finally.

Set your resolution to 42 and use the A4 size 210mmX297mm or inverted for portrait layout 297mmX210mm.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using illustrator to design a background for a word document I found these dimensions to work:

860px x 1060px

This is saved as a JPG at maximum quality and 72ppi

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You mention "*if* you're using Illustrator". It seems that the correct image dimensions shouldn't be dependent on what program is used to create the image. Can you clarify this in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I will give 2 method:

First

Step 1: Open Microsoft Word

Step 2: Add your picture in to the document

Step 3: Right click your picture

Step 4: Select Size and Position from the menu

Step 5: Select Text Wrapping at the top of the window that pops up

Step 6: Select In Front of Text

Second
Adobe Phothosop

1.Click File

2.Create New or Ctrl+N

3. Width: 800 pixels
   Height: 1122 pixels
   Resolution 300
4. Save image to jpg quality 12

And next step open ms. word
Page Layout > Page Color > Fill Effects > Picture > Select Picture.

Answer (score 0):

I found MS Word's `Watermark` menu very convenient because with the right image size you don't need to position it.

#### Correct Image size

To cover the full A4 area, create an image (jpg, png) with the following Dimensions:

- Width: `1190 px`
- Height: `1684 px`
- Resolution: `72 Pixels/Inch`

#### Add Bbackground image

In MS Word go to `Watermark`. It's in the `Design` tab.

Select `Picture...`and use "Scale" with `100%`. Uncheck `Washout`.

[image: Add background image as watermark]

Done.

#### Background Image Quality

If you want to save as PDF and you need more resolution I'd recommend to increase the image resolution to `2380 x 3368`.

Do the same as above but use use Scale with `50%`.

#### Image quality comparison

Here you can see PDFs zoomed in at 600% with 3 different watermark resolutions and their corresponding scale percentages:

[image: PDF zoom 600%]